# Could find the files in the lxc container after pushing them from host

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, containers, lxc

I don't have much experience on Ubuntu lxc. Basically, I have a vagrant machine with several containers running at the moment, and I want to push some files from my lxc host to one of my lxc containers. By following the lxc tutorial, I pushed the files but could not find it in the container.

My file path in the host: "video/init.mp4"

And I have created a directory "video" in the nginx with the path: "nginx/video"

The command I used for push my files:
`$ lxc file push video/init.mp4 nginx/video`

Command that for accessing the "nginx" container 
        `$ lxc exec nginx -- /bin/bash`

Hope someone could help me figure out where I did this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> And I have created a directory "video" in the nginx with the path: "nginx/video"

Do you mean you did something along the lines of:

```
lxc exec nginx -- mkdir /video
```

?

If so, then you would need to add '/' to the destination path, i.e.:

```
lxc file push video/init.mp4 nginx/video/
```

Otherwise it *should complain with "Error: Path already exists as a directory"